# How to fit a sine wave over activity data in r on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, trigonometry

I have activity data from a large dataset of which I'm trying to fit a sine wave to find the corresponding time points of the peak and troughs of activity. The data isn't necessarily sinusoidal which may be a problem, but I'd like to fit a curve nonetheless. I'm also a novice when it comes to rhythmic data and data analysis so feel free to provide new information or advice. Here's a link to the data of one mouse over the first week https://www.dropbox.com/s/m08vk7ovij2wcnb/stack_sine_dt.csv?dl=0

```
          id  eday   act      t
       <fctr> <int> <num>  <num>
    1:   M001     1    17  86400
    2:   M001     1    10  86460
    3:   M001     1    13  86520
    4:   M001     1    14  86580
    5:   M001     1    24  86640
   ---                          
10076:   M001     7     0 690900
10077:   M001     7     1 690960
10078:   M001     7     0 691020
10079:   M001     7     0 691080
10080:   M001     7     0 691140
```

I followed guidance from [this post here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77543/how-do-i-get-the-amplitude-and-phase-for-sine-wave-from-lm-summary) and got a decent graph, although the wave doesn't appear to peak and trough daily. I'm hoping to overlay it on a ggplot scatterplot.

```
# here I fit a wave using lm()
lmfit <- lm(data = dt,
            act ~ sin(2*pi*t/365.25) + cos(2*pi*t/365.25))
# then get relevant parameters
b0 <- coef(lmfit)[1]
alpha <- coef(lmfit)[2]
beta <- coef(lmfit)[3]

r <- sqrt(alpha^2 + beta^2)
phi <- atan2(beta, alpha)

# and fit it to some base plots
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
curve(b0 + r * sin(x + phi), 0, 2*pi, lwd=3, col="Gray",
      main="Overplotted Graphs", xlab="x", ylab="y")
curve(b0 + alpha * sin(x) + beta * cos(x), lwd=3, lty=3, col="Red", add=TRUE)
curve(b0 + r * sin(x + phi) - (b0 + alpha * sin(x) + beta * cos(x)), 
      0, 2*pi, n=257, lwd=3, col="Gray", main="Difference", xlab="x", y="")
```

Here are the outputs of the base plots and also the ggplot scatterplot that I'd like to lay the sine wave over.

[image][image]

Comment: Is there a frequency that one can assign to your data? Looks like your frequency is too low. You might want to use a linear combination of sines and cosines with varying frequencies as a model. In the end of the day, you will figure out which terms are significant. I will take a closer look at your problem once I get more time.

Comment: another way to phrase @slava-kohut's question: what units is `t` measured in? Seconds? The code you are using assumes that `t` is measured in days ...

Comment: Ah thank you! Yes it's measured in seconds. Should've specified that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that you have time measured in seconds and want a daily period, but the code you are using assumes that time is measured in days and that you want an annual period ...

```
x <- read.csv("stack_sine_dt.csv")

secs_per_day <- 24*3600
x$tday <- x$t/secs_per_day
lmfit <- lm(data = x,
            act ~ sin(2*pi*tday) + cos(2*pi*tday))
b0 <- coef(lmfit)[1]
alpha <- coef(lmfit)[2]
beta <- coef(lmfit)[3]

pframe <- data.frame(tday=seq(min(x$tday),max(x$tday),length=501))
pframe$act <- predict(lmfit,newdata=pframe)

library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(x,aes(tday,act))+
    geom_point(alpha=0.2) + geom_line(data=pframe,colour="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ben thanks for the great response. Your code works super well but I had to make one small modification. Is there a reason that you assigned pframe <- and included the length of seq() to be 501? That's not the length of the data frame I put on dropbox but all I had to do was change that and it worked! Hoping to clarify incase I'm missing something.

Comment: The prediction vector doesn't have to be the same length as the input vector.  Another alternative would be to use `pframe <- data.frame(tday=unique(x$tday))`

Answer (score 0):

Like this you can overlay the fitted curve on a ggplot scatter plot (I adapted the code from [here](https://gist.github.com/jwaage/4aa99783352100654980d20c93fae27e)):

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
# here I fit a wave using lm()
lmfit <- lm(data = dt,
            act ~ sin(2*pi*t/36500.25))

bind_cols(dt, lmfit %>% augment) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(t, act...3)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = .fitted - 1.96*.se.fit, ymax = .fitted + 1.96*.se.fit), alpha = 0.5) + geom_line(mapping = aes(y = .fitted), col = "red")
```

[image]